# How can cancel a Task in MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, task-parallel-library

i have a page with two command "RUN" "Cancel".
my question : how can when Click On "Cancel" from Task Into "RUN" cancel ?

TryTask :Start a Task
Cancel : Exit From Task TryTask

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource

        private async Task TryTask()
        {
            Task<int> task = Task.Run(() => slowFunc(1, 2), source.Token);

            // (A canceled task will raise an exception when awaited).

            source.Cancel();
            await task;
        }

        string someString = string.Empty;

        public int slowFunc(int a, int b)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 200000000; i++)
            {
                someString += "a";
                    source.Cancel();                    
                source.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            return a + b;
        }


        public async Task<ActionResult> Cancel()
        {
            "how cancel slow function"
        }
```

Comment: MVC wasn't designed to do this kind of work. Are you able to use SignalR?

Comment: SignalR when Deploy on IIS 8 Cancel Event dosn't work .. but in IIS 7.5 withot problem work .